# how to get next 3 month result using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

This is showing current month result and

i want next 3 month result how can i do this 
please help me to fix this issue

thanks

code

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where 
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `agreementdatee`) =
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
    ORDER BY CAST(flatno as SIGNED INTEGER) 
    DESC LIMIT 4");
```

complete code

```
 <?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost"; 

    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
     or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    echo "<br>";

    //select a database to work with
    $selected = mysql_select_db("building",$dbhandle) 
      or die("Could not select examples");


    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where 
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `agreementdatee`) =
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
    ORDER BY CAST(flatno as SIGNED INTEGER) 
    DESC LIMIT 4");

    //fetch tha data from the database 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo "Date: ".$row{'agreementdatee'}."  Name : ".$row{'buildingname'}."  Flat No: ". //display the results
       $row{'flatno'}."<br>";
    }
    //close the connection
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where 
    agreementdatee BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    ORDER BY CAST(flatno as SIGNED INTEGER) 
    DESC LIMIT 4");
```

This will select everything where agreementdatee is >= now and before or equal to 3 months in future

Comment: this is showing old year result also but i want current year result only how can i do this